# Unable to open Outlook app through UIActivityViewController in iOS 13 running devices

Tags: outlook, ms-office, ios13, xcode11, outlook-2016

Unable to open Microsoft Outlook app compose mail window with pre populated subject, body and recipients through UIActivityViewController Native iOS app running iOS 13.

- This functionality is working as expected in the previous iOS version < iOS 13
- Expect to open Microsoft Outlook app compose window with populated subject, body and recipients.
- I am not seeing any error at all.

EDITING (With other iOS apps)

I updated to iOS 13 and made sure all my apps were up to date. I had to send an email with multiple photos and I went to add them like I normally do, open photos, select the images, go to share them and select outlook. It would then open up Outlook with my photos and allow me to finish composing the email. With iOS 13 and Outlook, It wont let me do that anymore. When I try to select the photos, when I hit share with Outlook, I get a loading circle that appears for about half a second, and then nothing happens. So now I have to select the images one by one within the outlook app. Is this a bug in iOS 13 or a bug within the outlook app itself?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved with Outlook app version 4.5.0.